# can't delete object that has a many-to-many relationship

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-ctp5, ef-code-first

these are my **simplified** entities:

```
public class User : Entity
{
    public virtual ICollection<Role> Roles { get; set; }
}

public class Role : Entity
{
    public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
}

var user = dbContext.Set<User>().Find(id);
dbContext.Set<User>().Remove(user);
dbContext.SaveChanges(); // here i get error (can't delete because it's the     
//referenced by  join table roleUsers
```

the problems is that the join table references the user table and ef doesn't remove the records from the join table before deleting the user

I tried writing test cases and I noticed that:

if use the same context to add user with roles, save changes, remove and again save changes it works

but if I use 2 different contexts one for insert and another one for delete I get this error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must first clear Roles collection (user's roles must be loaded) before you will be able to remove user.

Comment: @Ladislav Mrnka In order to delete a user I have to somehow enforce the loading of all the "lazy" collections before deleting ?

Comment: @Omu: You can try other approach. Load the object from DB before deleting it (without collections).

Comment: @Ladislav Mrnka I'm doing dbContext.Set<User>().Remove(dbContext.Set<User>().Find(id)); dbContext.SaveChanges(); and i get the error

Comment: @Omu: Ok, I hoped it will work. Unfotunatelly it doesn't so you should follow my former advice from my answer.

Comment: @Ladislav Mrnka, is there some generic way of doing this ? I do this in a generic repository

Comment: @Omu: I don't think so unless you implement it by browsing metadata and looking for navigation properties. I also don't like the idea of generic repository. You always need to do something special.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to just get this deleting just do what the error is saying.

as a part of your DELETE method, you should do this, in order.

1) Get User including its related roles you can user User.Include(r=>r.roles)

2) iterate through and delete the roles for the given user   (make sure you use a toList() when you do this loop )

3) Delete the user

4) savechanges

Answer (score 0):

```
user.Roles
    .ToList()
    .ForEach(role => user.Roles.remove(role));

context.Users.remove(user);
context.SaveChanges();
```